# Is no reboot kernel patching enabled in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, canonical-livepatch

So one of the big features in kernel 4.0 is the ability to update the kernel without rebooting.  16.04 has kernel 4.0.  So therefore, is the no reboot feature enabled by default?  Or if not, is there a way to enable it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu has [livepatch](https://www.ubuntu.com/server/livepatch), which is a livepatching service for Ubuntu 16.04.

- https://www.ubuntu.com/server/livepatch
- http://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/10/20/live-kernel-patching-from-canonical-now-available-for-ubuntu/

Comment: Why does it require credentials to use?

Comment: @x0a , It's not part of the "free" base system. It's a paid for add on to Ubuntu Server sold by Canonical (Ubunut's parent company).

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

[On 20th October, 2016 Canonical officially announced the support for no reboot kernel patching](http://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/10/20/live-kernel-patching-from-canonical-now-available-for-ubuntu/), freely available on maximum three machines for a single user, check the article for details.

---

Yes, kernel hot patching is enabled in Ubuntu 16.04.

It was actually introduced in the first 4.0 series kernel on Ubuntu, with the 15.10 release, in October, 2015.

In a nutshell, any Ubuntu release currently having a official repository provided kernel (and mainline too) with version >=4.0 has live patching facility.

**Note:** Just to be clear, Ubuntu 16.04's kernel has the live patching capability, but Ubuntu offically does not provide any hot patch (as of now) as [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/828327/2165030) mentioned.

Comment: And how do i use that?

Comment: You're already using it.  Update your system with Software Updater, just like you normally do, and notice that you'll need to reboot even less often.

Comment: Are you sure? I don't see any patches being provided by ubuntu. You still need to reboot.

Comment: @iseletsk check the **note** section of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

It is now working

https://auth.livepatch.canonical.com/?user_type=ubuntu-user

```
sudo snap install canonical-livepatch
sudo canonical-livepatch enable TOKEN_FROM_ABOVE_LINK
```